# AngularJS: load JSON file in same folder (locally)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Previous questions haven't been satisfactory about this.

Most of AngularJS examples and tutorials online seem to always have tiny JSON arrays defined -inside- the js code...

So I'll reduce the code in a very basic sample:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

    app.controller('StoreController', function(){
        this.product = products;
    }); 

    var products = [
        {name: "Linux Mint", origin: "Ireland"},
        {name: "Ubuntu", origin: "Isle of Man"},
        {name: "OpenSUSE", origin: "Germany"},
        {name: "Fedora", origin: "USA"}
    ];
})();
```

I need to change the array "products" to load a json file -in the same folder-; no external tools or frameworks allowed and absolutely NO to setup servers and stuff as I have read in some previous answer.
No changing code either, only the part after the "=", perhaps using $scope and $http.

How would you do that in a working way?

Comment: as I said, I need to have the array in a json file and not in the code.

Comment: _NO to setup servers and stuff_ and _perhaps using $scope and $http._ you should start by learning the basics of client side vs server side and ajax before raising such ridiculous requirements in a question that doesn't make any sense. you can find a server that support CORS and is also serving json responses and use `$http` the fetch the json from there

Comment: this was referred to some answers I've found about previous similar questions.

Comment: You have 3 options to get the JSON: 1. Hard coded, 2. A json file that the user select from their local filesystem, 3. External resource - Server that you make a request and get back a response in a json format. `$scope` is how you're binding the json to the view, and `$http` is angular implementation to communicate with servers using `XMLHttpRequest` request

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store',[]);
    app.controller('StoreController',['$http',function($http){
        this.product=$http.get('file.json').success(function(resp){
            return resp.data;
        });
    }]);
})();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this you just need to have your json setup in your directory and point the get request to it like any other get. Hope this helps. *This is meant as purely to mimic a request, although some of this could be written closely the same for a server request.

```
function ExampleController(exampleSerivce) {
  var vm = this;
  exampleSerivce.getPosts().then(function(response) {
    vm.posts = response;
  });
}

function exampleSerivce() {
  var Posts = this,
    URLS = {
      FETCH: '/posts.json'
    },
    currentPostName,
    allPosts;

  Posts.getPosts = function() {
    return $http.get(URLS.FETCH).then(function(response) {
      return response.data
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FileReader` to read a local `JSON` file.  Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/LtYOyeyxJncnmBGw5YRp?p=preview

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.jsonString = "";

    $scope.readFromFile = function() {
        if(FileReader) {
            var input = document.getElementById('myFile');
            var file = input.files[0];

            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function(e) {
                $scope.jsonString = e.target.result;
                $scope.$apply();
            }

            fr.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            window.alert('FileReader is not found, sorry');
        }
    }
}]);
```